# Dynamically creating a columns in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am doing a project on hotels. In that Booking page all the room types and their availability, and their rates have to populate on a gridview for given dates.

Below are the roomtypes in the hotel admin page.

[image]

image below is binding room rates for the given date.
[image]

Currently I am binding data by using sql query for each cell.so it is taking much time to load the page.

I need a help to find a faster method to bind data.

code i have using is given below.

```
dim DTX AS new datatable
```

> /// sql command to load roomtypes.

```
While DR.Read
DTR = DTX.NewRow()
Dim datearray() As String = lbl_CheckInDate.Text.Split("/")
Dim XDT1 As New Date(CInt(datearray(2)), CInt(datearray(0)), CInt(datearray(1)))
DTR("Room Type") = DR("r_type").ToString
DTR("Book") = DR("r_id").ToString
     For x = 1 To 15
    tmpdt = Left(WeekdayName(Weekday(XDT1)), 3) & vbNewLine & Day(XDT1) & " " & Left(MonthName(Month(XDT1)), 3)
     price = Cls_function.GetTableData("select isnull(rent_a,0) as rent_a from tbl_HotelRoom where H_ID = " & Val(Request.QueryString("HID")) & " and r_id = " & Val(DR("r_id").ToString) & " and f_dt <= '" & Year(XDT1) & "-" & Month(XDT1) & "-" & Day(XDT1) & "' and t_dt >= '" & Year(XDT1) & "-" & Month(XDT1) & "-" & Day(XDT1) & "'")

If price = Nothing Then
        DTR(tmpdt) = Cls_function.GetTableData("select isnull(rent_a,0) as rent_a from tbl_HotelRoom where H_ID = " & Val(Request.QueryString("HID")) & " and r_id = " & Val(DR("r_id").ToString) & " and f_dt <= '" & Year(XDT1) & "-" & Month(XDT1) & "-" & Day(XDT1) & "' and t_dt >= '" & Year(XDT1) & "-" & Month(XDT1) & "-" & Day(XDT1) & "'")

Else
   DTR(tmpdt) = Format(price, "N")
End If
 XDT1 = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, XDT1)
Next
DTX.Rows.Add(DTR)
```

Comment: You're going to have to show some of your code.  The problem is likely more related to your sql queries than binding.

Answer (score 0):

Although not completely clear I am going to guess that you are calling the database for each of dates to get the room rate.  A better approach would be to write a stored procedure to return the room rates for the next X dates for a given room type.  If your sproc returns the data as multiple rows (rather than 1 row with many columns, as would be trickier SQL) then you could do some business logic manipulation to get the data in the format you need to easily bind it to the grid.